# Need to clear form on next page caused by link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently my pages are setup like this

1. Start at [category landing page](http://www.baopals.com/category/womens-clothing)
2. Click a link on the category landing page and you get sent to a search query result page IE `/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=FOO`

The undesired effect I am getting here is that when I click on a link in the category page it will take that search result and populate my search input on the next page.

I know how to clear the search input easily enough

`$( '#txtkey' ).val('')`

I just run into the problem of knowing to clear the search input when a link is clicked on the category page.

Is this only possible via `Ajax`? or is there some other way I can set this up

Answer (score 0):

The form is being filled because when the form is created on the page (likely with PHP) it's setup to put the GET variable `filter_name` into the default value.

For example:

- [...?route=product/search&**filter_name=hello**](http://www.baopals.com/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=hello) puts "hello" in the search field by default
- [...?route=product/search&**filter_name=world**](http://www.baopals.com/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=world) puts "world" in the search field by default

The fix here is to make that search form not put it out by default. We'd need to know more about your setup to help with that. Possibly there's a setting somewhere in your ecommerce management system, or you'd need to just remove the value attribute from the PHP code that outputs the form.

Comment: I might need to rewrite my question a bit im terrible at explaining. Currently the category pages are actually 100% html im hand picking search results and copying that link into the html landing page that is where the search form is getting populated

Comment: Look for the code used to display the search form on the page and add it to your original question. I think that'll clear the issue right up.